# Simple table with colspan giving errors with datatables

Tags: datatables

I have this simple html table

```
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Update</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>MyName</td>
            <td onclick="delete()">X</td>
            <td onclick="update()">U</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mytable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

If i open this on the browser i get

```
"Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined".
```

I don't undestand where is the problem.. I am following the official example: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your html have unmatched number of columns, notice the first row of your header has colspan while the second row doesn't.

what you can do is to provide a rowspan.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
        <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Update</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

here's a link to the datatables example of complex headers. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html